# Company options, price gone down but value gone up - is it a good deal?

Tags: options

This summer I signed a options deal with the company I work for that gives me the rights to buy shares 3 years from signing date. The deal is that I have to rights to buy X shares to price at signing date. So from three years from this summer, and if the price have gone up it is a good deal. If the price has gone down then I can choose not to execute the deal.

6 months has past and we have new investors coming in. A new options deal is on the table where it will, if accepted, replace the old one. The date for when I can execute the deal will be 3 years again.

Valuation of the company has gone up 6% but single stock price has gone down 40%.

Is a good deal for me?

One of the problems is that this company is a startup. New investors and new money will always come in. Lets say the company evaluated to 100M now. The next round will be 200M, and then 500M and then 1000M (for instance). If the company scales quickly I will get new "resets" before 3 years for the next 10 years? ALOT can happen in 10 years.

I can hold on to the summer deal. I will be -40% on the price but I think the price will go above that the next 10 years

Comment: There is no automatic answer  The question is always "What do _you_ think is going to happen to the stock's price in the future?"

Comment: Options are paper money and are better than lottery tickets only by so much. `New investors and new money will always come in` - that's a bold statement.

Comment: If the stock price has gone down, in what sense has the valuation gone up? Is this publicly traded? Is the strike price for the new options higher than the old one?